# Как плавно перемещать Bitmap в определенную сторону при нажатии?

Tags: java, android

Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии и удержании на левую часть экрана Bitmap(в моем случае ракета) плавно двигался влево, а при нажатии на правую вправо?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:



        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(event.getY()>(Game.heightDisplay/2))  {
                if(coordY > 930) {
                    coordY = 930;
                }
                else {
                    coordY= coordY + 5;
                }
            }
            else if(event.getY()<(Game.heightDisplay/2)) {

                if(coordY < 0) {
                    coordY = 0;
                }
                else {
                    coordY= coordY - 5;
                }
            }
            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
    }


    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Повесьте слушатель тача на экран.
2. В нём получите координаты нажатия.
3. Сравните их с размерами экрана.
4. Теперь у вас есть информация о том, на левую или правую часть экрана нажали.
5. В зависимости от этого меняете координату контейнера, содержащего картинку.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, получилось, но как можно сделать, чтобы движение было плавным?

Comment: @En1q0d, плавность=медленность. Просто за единицу времени перемещайте картинку на меньшее кол-во пикселей.

Comment: спасибо)А вот еще вопросик, а как можно сделать так, чтобы ракета двигалась влево или вправо, пока я нажимаю на кнопку.Просто сейчас я просто нажимаю, и она меняет координаты на 10 и все, приходится опять нажимать, чтобы сдвинуть?

Comment: @En1q0d, вроде, если вы будете проверять тип события, то должны быть вызваны `Action_DOWN`, `MOVE` и  `UP`. Если так, то вам надо двигать пока  `MOVE`. Если  `MOVE` не будет, то каждые n времени двигайте после события DOWN и прекращайте на UP

Comment: вот немного не понятно, что именно вписывать в DOWN.Пока добавил код самого метода, где все это дело происходит.

Comment: @En1q0d, если и так работает, то ничего больше писать не надо. Если при неподвижном пальце не работает, то придётся делать что-то типа `Timer` + `TimerTask` коий будет периодически вызываться и двигать картинку. Вызывать надо будет в Down, а останавливать в Up

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38809/discussion-between-en1q0d-and-).